# Changing GTK ComboBox model after creation

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygobject

Python GTK:  So, I have 3 combo boxes where employees will be able to select their department, building, and floor.  Originally I had it so on the department combo box changed, it would create a new combo box with a model of all the buildings belonging to that department, and similarly with the floor combo box.  The problem with this is that it doesn't let the user go back and change their selections.  Ideally I would like 3 combo boxes, and after selecting the department, it would load a new model into the already created combo box and update it.  I'm using tree models as I also have another value in there that I'm handling to sort the model that is being created.

```
self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=6)

    # Department
    self.department_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(self.logic.get_department_store())
    self.department_combo.connect("changed", self.on_department_combo_changed)
    self.department_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.department_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.department_combo.show()
    self.vbox.show()
    # Building
    self.building_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_entry()
    self.building_combo.connect("changed", self.on_building_combo_changed)
    self.building_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.building_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.building_combo.show()
    #Floor
    self.floor_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_entry()
    self.floor_combo.connect("changed", self.on_floor_combo_changed)
    self.floor_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.floor_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.floor_combo.show()

def on_department_combo_changed(self, combo):
    tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
    if tree_iter != None:
        model = combo.get_model()
        name, row_id = model[tree_iter][:2]
        print name
        print row_id
        print("Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name))
        self.selectedDepartment = name
        self.building_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(self.logic.get_building_store(self.selectedDepartment))
        self.building_combo.show()
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.building_combo, False, False, 0)
    return
```

I have no problem selecting the proper department, I just can't get the Building combo box to update with a new model.  I've searched through the documentation quite a bit, and may just be being blind.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not try self.building_combo.set_model() instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Thanks, I was just being blind apparently...  I see that in the documentation now.